# Why all questions from tags I follow don't highlight as I suppose they should?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

As you can see I follow the tag "thermodynamics". And only a few questions are highlighted. Why?

I use: Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image: TAGS]

Comment: Works OK for me. Have you tried to delete cookies for `*.stackexchange.com` and log back in? Probably not directly related to the problem, but questions like this are usually better received if you mention OS and web browser (and their versions) you are using.

Comment: @andselisk yes I already delete my full history and restarted my computer twice.

Comment: I didn't say history, I said *cookies*, it's a different thing (for Chromium-based browsers it's *Settings → Site Settings → Cookies → See all cookies and site data* → search for `stackexchange.com` and click *Remove All Shown*). On a funny note, you should've rebooted three times:) (Reference: [YouTube — The Website is Down #1](https://youtu.be/uRGljemfwUE?t=63))

Comment: @andselisk I already deleted everything. When you delete history you can choose to delete cookies as well. :)

Comment: Weird. If switching to another browser won't help, then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: It's not a bug at all. You were looking at questions in this tag only - they would be all yellow, and that would be pointless, so only questions from *other* favored tags were highlighted. BTW you can't be serious you did all that your comp for this reason o.O

Comment: @Mithoron I don't understand any of your sentence in your comment. Except the first one which frustrate me a lot.

Comment: Oh boy, I haven't noticed `[thermodynamics]` in the search field and I thought I'm looking at the unsorted list of questions (probably due to my ancient SXGA screen). @Mithoron is 100% correct, this is an intended behavior. I'm sorry that you had to clean your history.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature.

While on the normal question site all [thermodynamics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermodynamics) questions will show up highlighted, you have just *searched* for questions with [thermodynamics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermodynamics) (note it says `[thermodynamics]` in the search bar on the top of the page). In the search view, only those questions are highlighted that have *another* tag you follow in addition to [thermodynamics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermodynamics). If I had to guess, you also favourited [kinetics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinetics) which would be why the question on the top of the list is highlighted.

The reason behind this feature is that an all-yellow list would provide exactly zero information.